# Async Controller Action with Umbraco 7 returns string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco, async-await

Is it possible to use an async action within an Umbraco SurfaceController (and UmbracoApiController)

I tried the following code

```
public async Task< ActionResult> HandleLogin(LoginViewModel model)
{
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    return PartialView("Login", model);
}
```

and although it compiled correctly when the action is called the action seems to return as soon as the await is hit, and returns a string

> System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult]

the controller of course inherits from **SurfaceController** and I wonder if this is the problem?

If this is not possible, are there any workarounds to achieve async action behaviour?

Any help would be gratefully received!

Comment: I'm not familiar with Umbraco, but the fact that it's converting `Task<ActionResult>` to a string indicates that it does not understand `async` methods. You might need to contact the Umbraco community directly, and/or put in a feature request.

Comment: Thanks, yeah I thought it might be somethign like that.  Have asked a question on our.umbraco too.  Will update here if any feedback!

Comment: I have posted a similar problem on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30166566/umbraco-7-asp-net-mvc-async-controller-returning-system-threading-tasks-task1 using a RenderMvcController - any luck with this?? It's a year later but still the same problem! Am I missing something?

Comment: This issue has been fixed for controllers that inherit from `Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController` but this is still an issue for controllers that implement IRenderMvcController. I've raised it as an issue [here](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-7270) and written about  [a workaround here](http://www.digbyswift.com/blog/2015/10/asyncawait-in-umbraco-custom-controllers/).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SurfaceControllers in Umbraco ultimately derive from *System.Web.Mvc.Controller* However they have custom action invoker (*RenderActionInvoker*) set.

*RenderActionInvoker* inherits from *ContollerActionInvoker*.  In order to process async actions it should instead derive from *AsyncContolkerActionInvoker*. *RenderActionInvoker* overrides only the findaction method so changing to derive from *AsyncContolkerActionInvoker* is easy.

Once I recompiled Umbraco.Web with this change, async actions worked fine.

Rather than recompiling the whole project, I guess you could specify a new actioninvoker on each class

```
public class RenderActionInvokerAsync : System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker
{

    protected override ActionDescriptor FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, string actionName)
    {
        var ad = base.FindAction(controllerContext, controllerDescriptor, actionName);

        if (ad == null)
        {
            //check if the controller is an instance of IRenderMvcController
            if (controllerContext.Controller is IRenderMvcController)
            {
                return new ReflectedActionDescriptor(
                    controllerContext.Controller.GetType().GetMethods()
                        .First(x => x.Name == "Index" &&
                                    x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NonActionAttribute), false).Any() == false),
                    "Index",
                    controllerDescriptor);

            }
        }
        return ad;
    }

}

public class TestController : SurfaceController
{

    public TestController() {
        this.ActionInvoker = new RenderActionInvokerAsync();
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Test()
    {
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        return PartialView("TestPartial");

    }
}
```

Haven't tested this way of doing things though.

Comment: Thanks Pete.  Your answer helped me solved my own issue with this problem (though not with Umbraco).  In MVC5, my `ControllerFactory` was hooking up an old `ActionInvoker` for hooking into ELMAH that was inheriting from `ControllerActionInvoker`.  When I changed this to `AsyncControllerActionInvoker` the problem was resolved.

Answer (score 4):

Just FYI I've added an issue to the tracker for this:
http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U4-5208

There is a work around though:

Create a custom async render action invoke (as per above):

```
public class FixedAsyncRenderActionInvoker : System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker
{
    protected override ActionDescriptor FindAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, ControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor, string actionName)
    {
        var ad = base.FindAction(controllerContext, controllerDescriptor, actionName);

        if (ad == null)
        {
            //check if the controller is an instance of IRenderMvcController
            if (controllerContext.Controller is IRenderMvcController)
            {
                return new ReflectedActionDescriptor(
                    controllerContext.Controller.GetType().GetMethods()
                        .First(x => x.Name == "Index" &&
                                    x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(NonActionAttribute), false).Any() == false),
                    "Index",
                    controllerDescriptor);

            }
        }
        return ad;
    }

}
```

Create a custom render mvc controller:

```
public class FixedAsyncRenderMvcController : RenderMvcController
{
    public FixedAsyncRenderMvcController()
    {
        this.ActionInvoker = new FixedAsyncRenderActionInvoker();
    }
}
```

Create a custom render controller factory:

```
public class FixedAsyncRenderControllerFactory : RenderControllerFactory
{
    public override IController CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, string controllerName)
    {
        var controller1 = base.CreateController(requestContext, controllerName);
        var controller2 = controller1 as Controller;
        if (controller2 != null)
            controller2.ActionInvoker = new FixedAsyncRenderActionInvoker();
        return controller1;
    }
}
```

Create an umbraco startup handler and replace the necessary parts with the above custom parts:

```
public class UmbracoStartupHandler : ApplicationEventHandler
{
    protected override void ApplicationStarting(UmbracoApplicationBase umbracoApplication, ApplicationContext applicationContext)
    {
        DefaultRenderMvcControllerResolver.Current.SetDefaultControllerType(typeof(FixedAsyncRenderMvcController));

        FilteredControllerFactoriesResolver.Current.RemoveType<RenderControllerFactory>();
        FilteredControllerFactoriesResolver.Current.AddType<FixedAsyncRenderControllerFactory>();

        base.ApplicationStarting(umbracoApplication, applicationContext);
    }
}
```