# How to create an instance of a model that inherits RenderModel inside UmbracoApiController?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm using Umbraco CMS. I have the following model:

```
 public class LoyaltyPromo : RenderModel
    {
        public LoyaltyPromo(IPublishedContent content)
            : base(content)
        {
        }
        //properties removed for brevity
    }
```

I want to use this model inside `UmbracoApiController`. So i do this:

```
    public class PromoServiceController : UmbracoApiController
        {
            public async Task<object> GetAll()
            {

                var umbracoHelper = new UmbracoHelper(UmbracoContext.Current);
                IPublishedContent content = umbracoHelper.TypedContent(1050);
                var list = new List<LoyaltyPromo>();
                list.Add(new LoyaltyPromo(content));
                return list;

            }
        }
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, i get the `NullReferenceException`:

[image: Screenshot where the exception occurs]

> An error has occurred. 
>   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>   
>   System.NullReferenceException
>    at Umbraco.Web.Models.RenderModel..ctor(IPublishedContent
>   content) at LoyaltyOps.Models.LoyaltyPromo..ctor(IPublishedContent
>   content) in C:\Users\mkallingal\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\LoyaltyOps\LoyaltyOps.Models\LoyaltyPromo.cs:line 13 at
>   LoyaltyOps.Controllers.PromoServiceController.d__0.MoveNext()
>   in C:\Users\mkallingal\documents\visual studio
>   2015\Projects\LoyaltyOps\LoyaltyOps\Controllers\PromoServiceController.cs:line
>   32 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was
>   thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.d__3`1.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.d__0.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.d__2.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()

How can i resolve this?

Comment: I think you're going to need to extend your code example so we can see LoyaltyPromo.cs:line 13 where it says the null reference is occurring?

Comment: Hi @ProNotion,  13th line is `public LoyaltyPromo(IPublishedContent content)
            : base(content)
        {
        }`

Comment: You are taking the publishedcontent node using a hardcoded id, eg. 1050. Are you sure this id exists?

Comment: Hi @Mivaweb, yes it exists. I copied it from Umbraco ->`Content`->`Promos-List` (content name) -> Id (from the `Properties` tab) . `IPublishedContent content = umbracoHelper.TypedContent(1050);` returns all the info of the content;  it's not null.

Comment: I see you are using async task, check this solution on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23006976/async-controller-action-with-umbraco-7-returns-string/23033649#23033649

Comment: @Mivaweb, i've added a screenshot on the question where the error occurs. I tried without using async, but still gets the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that RenderModel is not intended to be used within WebAPI, which has no context regarding a front end page at all.  Internally RenderModel is relying on the `PublishedContentRequest` property of `UmbracoContext` being set properly, which doesn't happen with WebAPI.

If you really do need to base your model on RenderModel, then use the alternative constructor:

`RenderModel(IPublishedContent content, CultureInfo culture)`

And pass in the culture as well as the content - this will get around the need for `PublishedContentRequest` being set, but you may run into other problems further on.

The better approach would be to create a view model that doesn't rely on RenderModel at all.  Since WebAPI typically serialises your model to JSON anyway, the lighter you can make it the better.

One other thing - your listing for GetAll() doesn't return at all - I assume there's no extra processing going on in your actual method that requires your model to be based on `RenderModel`, and you're just returning the list?

Comment: I was using the model inside `RenderMvcController`. I thought i could reuse it inside `UmbracoApiController`. I suppose i'm not allowed to do it. So like you suggested, i created a seperate model to cater for `RenderMvcController` and make `LoyaltyPromo` to not inherit from `RenderModel`.